# echo returns only one result from database

Tags: php

I have 2 database tables users and gallery, the page will show unlimited profile if the user has a gallery it will show under there profile picture.

currently there are 2 users in the DB user 1 has 5 gallery images user 2 has none.

users and gallery table are joined by D = ID field in both tables.

the first user shows up with his gallery underneath his profile but user 2 does not show at all, every new user and gallery if they have one is to show under each other like a list. but it echos out the first user and his gallery and that's it..

if I  WHERE U.ID = U.ID  in the query to  WHERE U.ID = 1 or 2  it will show both users just not at the same time in a list..

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `ID` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `FullName` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `JobTitle` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `Bio` text,
  `Photo` text,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `gallery` (
  `GalleryID` bigint(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GalleryImage` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;




<?php 


$stmt = $db->prepare("
SELECT U.ID,
       U.FullName,
       U.Email,
       U.JobTitle,
       U.Bio,
       U.Photo, 
       group_concat(G.GalleryImage) as GalleryImage 
FROM users as U 
join gallery as G 
ON U.ID = G.ID 
WHERE U.ID = U.ID 

 ");


$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();


 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $ID = $row['ID'];        
        $FullName = $row['FullName'];    
        $Email = $row['Email'];   
        $JobTitle = $row['JobTitle'];
        $Bio = $row['Bio'];
        $Photo = $row['Photo'];         
        $GalleryImage = explode(',', $row['GalleryImage']);

        if (isset($Photo) && ! empty($Photo)) {
            $ProfileImage = "$Photo";
        } else {
            $ProfileImage= "avatar.jpg";
        }


   echo "<div class='container team-wrap'>
           <div class='row'>
             <div class='col-md-6'>
             <img class='img-responsive' src='$ProfileImage'>
               </div>
                 <div class=\"col-md-6\">
                    <strong>$FullName<br>$JobTitle</strong>
                      <br>
                      <p>$Bio</p>
                      <a href='mailto:$Email' class='btn btn-info'>Contact Me</a>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>";

     echo "

  <br>
<br>
<br>   

";

   echo "<div class='container team-wrap'>";   

   foreach ($GalleryImage as $img){        
       if (isset($img) && ! empty($img)) { 

           //Display this row as many times as needed by data in this row.
           echo "<img style='height: 100px; width: 100px;' src='cdn/assets/gallery/$img'>";       

       } else { 

           echo "NO IMAGES";
       }

   }


}  

echo"</div>";
?>
```

Comment: So what's the issue? You can always use [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) to check how many rows are returned.

Comment: SELECT G.GameID,G.GameName,G.GameCover,group_concat(M.ModName) FROM Games as G join Mods as M ON G.GameID = M.GameID group by G.GameID

Comment: I am assuming this must be pretty difficult lots of views but no answer I don't feel so bad now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$checker = array();
$profileArray = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $profileArray[$row['ID']]['GalleryImages'][] = $row['GalleryImage'];
    if(!in_array($row['ID'], $checker))
    {
        while (list ($key, $value) = each($row))
        {
            if($key != 'GalleryImage')
            {
                $profileArray[$row['ID']][$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        $checker[] = $row['ID'];
    }
}

foreach ($profileArray as $row)
{
    $ID = $row['ID'];
    $FullName = $row['FullName'];
    $Email = $row['Email'];
    $JobTitle = $row['JobTitle'];
    $Bio = $row['Bio'];
    $Photo = $row['Photo'];
    $GalleyImages = $row['GalleryImages'];

    if (isset($Photo) && !empty($Photo))
    {
        $ProfileImage = "$Photo";
    }
    else
    {
        $ProfileImage = "avatar.jpg";
    }

    $output .= "
    <div class='container yep team-wrap'>
      <div class='row'>        
        <div class='col-md-6'>
            <img class='img-responsive' src='cdn/assets/artist/$ProfileImage'>
        </div>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
      <strong>$FullName<br>$JobTitle</strong>
         <br>
        <p>$Bio</p>
       <a href='mailto:$Email' class='btn btn-info'>Contact Me</a>
    </div> 
</div>";

    //End of info row
    $output .= "<br /><br /><br />";

    //Start Gallery Row
    $output .= "
        <div class='row'>
         <div class='col-md-12'>
        <div id='gallery-slider' class='slider responsive'>";

    if(!empty($GalleyImages))
    {
        foreach ($GalleyImages as $img)
        {
            //Display this row as many times as needed by data in this row.
            $output .= "<img class='img-responsive' src='cdn/assets/gallery/$img'>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $output .= "HTML THAT YOU WANNA DISPLAY instead of images";
    }

    $output .= "
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>";
}
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this SQL in your code.

```
SELECT u.ID, u.Email, u.FullName, u.JobTitle, u.Bio, u.Photo,GROUP_CONCAT(g.GalleryImage) GalleryImage
FROM `users` u, `gallery` g 
WHERE u.ID = g.ID GROUP BY u.ID
```

Comment: is GROUP_CONCAT() give you a comma delimited string?

Comment: Yes. You need to explode it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the name of the table before of the table in the **WHERE** like:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM Games, Mods WHERE Games.GameID = Mods.GameID");
```

This is for identified the ambiguous(duplicate) name of the two tables in the query....

I recommend use the keyword JOIN for relationship of tables..

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM Games JOIN Mods ON Games.GameID = Mods.GameID");
```

Better in your case, can you use the function **USING()** because the two tables have the same name of column, like:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM Games JOIN Mods USING(GameID)");
```

Answer (score 0):

use `JOIN` and `Group_concat`  you will get comma separated Modname like this `mod1,mod2,..` .

```
SELECT G.GameID,
       G.GameName,
       G.GameCover,
       group_concat(M.ModName) as ModName 
FROM Games as G 
join Mods as M 
ON G.GameID = M.GameID 
group by G.GameID
```

**output:**

```
 GameID    GameName    GameCover     ModName

   1        Benten       g1           mod1,mod2,mod3
```

Comment: @jyothih if I add a ModImageCover  it does not show all of them.

Comment: try this one SELECT G.GameID,
       G.GameName,
       G.GameCover,M.ModName as ModName 
FROM Games as G 
join Mods as M 
ON G.GameID = M.GameID

Comment: @jyothih  still having issues with it now game 2 don't show and game 1 repeats for each mod

Comment: @JYoThI Please delete your comment on the question that offers a query.  That is not what comments are for.